# Browser not loading simple javascript

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am trying to create a simple javascript project but I am facing a very simple issue. My javascript source code is not being loaded from my browser. I have simplified the code for simplicity:

```
<!DOCTYPE > <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Testing works</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      type="text/javascript"
      src="main.js"
    </script>
    <main>
      <h1>My Page works</h1>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my simple javascript:

```
console.log('javascript source working')
alert("Message")
```

The Devtools from chrome displays the following

[image]

I have enabled javascript on my chrome. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag is closing too soon

```
    <script>
      type="text/javascript"
      src="main.js"
    </script>
```

needs to be

```
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="main.js">
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo:

```html
<!-- no closing bracket before attributes -->
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="main.js">
</script>
```

Furthermore, scripts are usually declared on a single line (open-close). This is convention.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
```

---

Unrelated, but kind of related :-

You may have seen the self-closing tag convention in various elements such as `<link />` and `<meta />` elements. You cannot do the following, because [*"both the starting and ending tag[s] are mandatory"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script).

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" /> <!-- not possible -->
```

Although it would be nice if you could…